# Bind on jquery autocomplete event with djselectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, autocomplete

I want to execute personal code when jQuery autocomplete open the choice list.

I have a autocomplete input:

```
<input type="text" name="myinputtext" id="myinputtext" ... >
```

I have wrote this javascript:

```
$('#myinputtext').on('autocompleteopen', function(event, item) {
   alert('hello');
});
```

But my code is not executed when i use autocmplete, where i'm wrong ?

**Edit**: I previously ask this question without ask about djselectable (django). So responses will now (after my edit) like out of question. So i edit the question and add my answer for future visitors with this problem.

Comment: Did you try specifying an `open` callback when initializing autocomplete?

Comment: `.bind()` is deprecated, please use `.on()`.

Comment: After changing the code in your question.. does it still not work? Did you put it between document.ready?

Comment: @PlantTheIdea edited and tested, same result.

Comment: Wasn't expecting it to fix the problem, more a note. Can we see your code that binds the autocomplete?

Comment: Does `#myinputtext` exist when you add the event handler?  If not, the `on`/`bind` won't do anything in this format.

Comment: @SalmanA Nop (i will check, because autocomplete ise placed by a plugin in my project). Can i see all binded thigs with a code line ?

Comment: @putvande Code still don't work, and yes, it's in document.ready (whatever i test it with firebug)

Comment: Is `#myinputtext` generated dynamically?  Does it exist when the page initially loads?

Comment: @JeffB yes exist when page load. +Note: i will add a note in question

Comment: @PlantTheIdea Difficult to expose entire code, this portion is included in django, with form generation etc ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With dj-selectable need to use *djselectableopen* event:

```
$('#myinputtext').on('djselectableopen', function(){
  alert('Hello world');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not familiar with django but jQuery UI autocomplete works like this:

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-open

```
$('#someInput').autocomplete({
    source: someObject,
    open: function(){

        alert('do something when the autocomplete suggestions have appeared');

    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Please try like this.

```
$( "#myinputtext" ).autocomplete({
    source: something,
    open: function (event, ui){
        alert ('hello')         
    }
});
```